# Vectorization of the nonzero entries of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, vectorization

I am familiar with the $\textrm{vec}(A)$ operator, where the columns of a matrix $A$ are stacked into a vector. If my matrix $A$ has zero-entries, is there a standard notation/operator like $\textrm{vec}(A)$, which would similarly stack the columns of $A$ but ignores the zero-entries?

Comment: I'd be surprised if there is standard notation for this. Invent your own!

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplication_and_elimination_matrices#Elimination_matrix) might be relevant.